# One point compactification and field extension

Tags: general-topology, extension-field

We know that a topological space $X$ has a one point compactification if there exist a compact set $Y$ having $X$ as a subspace,where $Y\setminus X$ contains a single point Also for two such $Y$ and $Y'$ we have a homeomorphism which is identity on $X$.
Now in the theory of fields,we know for any polynomial $p(x)\in F[x]$ ($F$ is a field) there exist an extension $F'$ of $F$ such that $p$ has root. Also for any two such $F'$ and $F''$ we have an isomorphism between $F'$ and $F''$ which is identity on $F$.

There is too much similarity in the spirit of these two theorem. My question is there any common philosophy behind the proof of these statements?

Comment: The property for fields you want is that there exists an extension $F'$ (which we can define as $F[X]/(p(X))$) such that, for any extension $F''$ in which $p(X)$ has a root, there exists a unique morphism of fields $F'\to F''$ that is the identity on $F$.  Both of these theorems should be instances of [initial objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) in a category.